# Make [one-hot-encoding] a synonym for [one-hot]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[one-hot-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/one-hot-encoding) currently has no description, while [one-hot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/one-hot) at least has a nominal one.

As far as I can tell (since the description of one-hot includes the term "encoding"), these are exactly the same tags.  In fact several questions that are tagged with one are tagged with the other, i.e.:

- [Generate one-hot vector from a nx1 array of binary labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070350/generate-one-hot-vector-from-a-nx1-array-of-binary-labels)
- [Reducing one hot encoding to one dimension for Keras Feed Forward Neural Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954834/reducing-one-hot-encoding-to-one-dimension-for-keras-feed-forward-neural-network)
- [One Hot Encoding using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592324/one-hot-encoding-using-numpy)
- [One Hot Encoding giving same number for different words in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591078/one-hot-encoding-giving-same-number-for-different-words-in-keras)

I have no privileges in this tag, so I leave it to the community...

Comment: The description can be trivially added or changed. Which of these tags do you think is better/more descriptive? That one should become the master tag, and the other should be merged into it.

Comment: I had been assuming we should make [tag:one-hot] the master and [tag:one-hot-encoding] merged in, just because it seemed simplest.  However, [tag:one-hot-encoding] sounds more descriptive to me, and would likely serve better as a master.  For what it's worth, there are 46 [tag:one-hot-encoding] questions and 20 [tag:one-hot] questions, so I'm guessing the users of the tag prefer [tag:one-hot-encoding], 2 to 1.

Comment: I almost mistook [one-hot] at the end of this question for [on hold] :P

Comment: In all of Stack Overflow, there are a total of 3 users who can suggest adding [one-hot] as a synonym for [one-hot-encoding] and a total of 6 who could possibly vote on the suggestion.  It's not likely that the community will create this synonym on its own, without direct intervention.